# Javascript not working on chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I made a html file to use as chrome extension.
If I open the html file everything works. But when I upload the extension the buttons don't function.

HTML:

```html
                        <button onclick="generate()">Generate</button>
                        <button onclick="copyPassword()">Copy</button>
```

Javascript:

```js
//generate random password
function generate(){
    //set password length
    let complexity = document.getElementById("slider").value;

    //possible characters
    let values = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW0123456789`~!@#$%^&*()_-+=][{}':;><,./?\|";

    let password = "";

    //create for loop to choose password characters
    for(var i = 0; i <= complexity; i++){
        password = password + values.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(values.length - 1)));
    }

    //add password to textbox
    document.getElementById("display").value = password;

    //add password to previously passwords section
    document.getElementById("lastNums").innerHTML += password + "<br />";
}

//set default length display of 25
document.getElementById("length").innerHTML = "Length: 25";

//function to set length based on slider position
document.getElementById("slider").oninput = function(){
    if(document.getElementById("slider").value > 0){
        document.getElementById("length").innerHTML = "Length: " + document.getElementById("slider").value;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("length").innerHTML = "Length: 1";
    }
}

//function to copy password
function copyPassword(){
    document.getElementById("display").select();

    document.execCommand("Copy");
}
```

Thanks for helping me out.

~~BE

Comment: Do you have a manifest.json included in the root of your extension folder?

Comment: If you're going to make snippets, make sure it makes sense to do so.  Your second snippet does not have the HTML elements available, so it does not work.

Comment: I have the manifest and the elements are there but I didnt show them up

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Javascript in Chrome Extension -> Basic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205823/run-javascript-in-chrome-extension-basic)

Comment: No, @JoshLee it isn't